# Appending Lists Twice

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how create a program that can recommend users friends based on the friends they have in common. Particularly if two people are mutual friends I want to put their user IDs into a list. For example if User A is mutual friends with B and C I want A's list to look like:

```
A: [B, C]
```

And if B is only friends with A I want B's list to look like:

```
B: [A]
```

How do I append the list so that a particular user's friend IDs will be put into the user's list?

This is the code I have so far.

```
def open_file():
      '''Remember the docstring'''
      Done = False
      while not Done: 
        try:
           file_name = input("Enter a filename: ") 
           file_pointer = open(file_name)
           Done = True
           return file_pointer

       except FileNotFoundError:
           print("File not found. Please try a different filename: ")

 def read_file(file_pointer):  
      ''' Remember the docstring'''
     # Read n and initizlize the network to have n empty lists -- 
     #    one empty list for each member of the network
     n = file_pointer.readline()
     n = int(n)
     network = []
     user_chosen = int(input("Please pick a number within the correct range: "))
     for user_chosen in range(n):
        network.append([])
     else:
       print("Error: input must be an int within the correct range.")
     return network
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: Your function indentations arent' quite right. Can you fix that for readability?

Comment: `Done = True` makes no sense after `return file_pointer`.

Comment: Sorry I fixed the indentation, I put the Done = True there so it would keep looping until it got a data file that existed. I changed the location though so I hope it makes sense now

Comment: Your loop statement `for user_chosen in range(n):` right after defining the value of `user_chosen` does not do what you think it does--it destroys and forgets the previous value of `user_chosen`. You also have style issues with your docstrings and with never closing the file you opened.